# replace APC smart signaling cable with RJ-45 to RJ-45

Tags: ups, cable, serial, apc

Is it possible to replace the APC Smart Signaling Cable PN: 940-1525A with an RJ-45 to RJ-45 cable?

The cable is built as an RJ-50 to DB9, but I need to connect it to a console server that only uses RJ-45. I have pin-out diagrams that show the cable pin-out...but I do not know how to convert the DB-9 pin-out to RJ-45.

[APC cable diagram](https://alioth-lists.debian.net/pipermail/nut-upsuser/2005-August/000118.html)

[940-1525A cable diagram](https://pinoutguide.com/UPS/apc_0625_cable_pinout.shtml)

Initially, I made a rollover cable for the serial connection as our Console server works with that. However, the UPS was not pleased with this cable and switched off my power outputs. It seems the cable might need to be shielded RJ-45 with possibly a soldered wire on the shield? I have never made a cable like that. So, is it possible to replace this serial cable with an RJ-45 to RJ-45 solution?

Edited to add the 940-1525A cable diagram, and changed the connector as-built from RJ45 to RJ-50

Answer (score 1):

The APC act that way as it receive signal on one of it's pin that control the turn off  and when it do it turn off. Standard serial cable don't work on APC either as they have special pinout. I dont suggest to make such custom cable.

I would suggest to order a network management card for your APC. Something like https://www.apc.com/shop/ca/en/products/APC-UPS-Network-Management-Card-2/P-AP9630 if it fit.

Comment: yeah we actually have the NMC installed, but are looking for serial connectivity as an optional fallback.